# MonoTouch.Dialog: embed view of another UIViewController into a ViewElement?

Tags: c#, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a view controller that manages a four digit PIN pad. This controller is used to access my app.

However, I would like to use the same PIN pad when changing the PIN.
The controller to change the PIN is a MT.DialogViewController with one section and one row, namely a `ViewElement`. That `ViewElement` holds the view of the PIN pad controller.
This kind of works, but `ViewWillAppear` etc aren't called reliably. 
I have also tried to use UIViewController containment by calling (in the MT.Dialog c'tor) `addChildViewController`, then add the ViewElement and then call `didMoveToParentViewController`.
Still, I'm getting problems upon rotation and the VieWill/Did*() methods aren't called.
Is there a solution for this (either clean or dirty, I don't care)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you re-factor the PIN pad from a ViewController to a UIView (and then stick the UIView containing the PIN pad back into the UIViewController)?

Doing so should let you put the PIN pad UIView inside a ViewElement, which I suspect will result in improved rendering on Orientation changes and consistent ViewDid/Will method calls.

Comment: Not an option. The controller does lots of, well, controlling.